# Porque nunca se visita la segunda condición en el Update()

Tags: c#, unity

ante todo gracias por leer.

Mi pregunta es, porque nunca entro en la segunda condición del Update(),
quiero conseguir mediante el raycast, tener el nombre del gameObject clicado, pero es como que la posición donde clico nunca contiene ningun gameObject...

Los gameObjects se generan en ejecución mediante otro script.

Generador de los objetos:

```
//public Color aColor = new Vector4(0, 0, 1, 1);

public GameObject prefab;
public int numberToCreate;

public List<GameObject> positions;
// Use this for initialization

GameObject newObj;
void Start()
{
    positions = new List<GameObject>();
    Populate();

}

private void Populate()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < numberToCreate; i++)
    {
        newObj = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, transform);
        newObj.name = i.ToString();
        newObj.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.white;
        newObj.AddComponent<BoardClick>();
        newObj.GetComponent<BoardClick>().pos = i;
        positions.Add(newObj);
    }
}
//UnityEngine.Random.ColorHSV();

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}
```

Controlador de clicks:

```
public int pos;

void Start()
{

}

public void OnMouseDown(List<GameObject> position)
{
    var myname = name;
    //Debug.Log("Clicked " + pos.ToString() + " " + this.name.ToString());
    Debug.Log(myname);
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        //Debug.Log("Click");
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        Debug.Log(ray.ToString() + " " );
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
        {
            Debug.Log("Hello");
            Debug.Log(ray.ToString() + " "+ hit.ToString());
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.gameObject.name);


        }
    }

}
```

Llego a conseguir el string del "Click" pero nunca consigo entrar en el siguiente if...

Screen:
[image: Info en ejecución]

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: Raycast checkea si has clickeado siempre que el objecto tenga un Collider, asi que al crear el objecto añadele un Collider, si ya has solucionado esto entonces suerte con tus projectos! ^^

Comment: Pero actualmente los botones del 0 al 8 tienen un box collider, es ese? O tengo que poner otro? Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Okay creo que ya se tu problema, por lo que veo estas intentando hacer raycast a una imagen(u otro objecto) dentro de un canvas, con lo cual no se pueden añadir Colliders a esa 'Imagen'(supongamos). Para eso tengo esta solucion:

Cambia el codigo(O crea uno nuevo para testear) de 'BoardClick'

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class BoardClick : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler {

    public int pos;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    public void OnMouseDown(List<GameObject> position)
    {
        var myname = name;
        //Debug.Log("Clicked " + pos.ToString() + " " + this.name.ToString());
        Debug.Log(myname);
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("You have clicked the gameObject:" + " " + gameObject.name);
        Debug.Log("Hello");
    }
}
```

OnPointerDown es lo mismo que OnMouseDown pero para objetos de 'UI', tambien puede ser utilizado para Android

Espero que te ayude!

Comment: voy a probar, pero realmente el objeto si tiene un collider ...